# pyqt5 - change text and background color:

Tags: pyqt5

I would like to change the background color and the text color of sub-menus.

Here's an example of text color changing:

```
q_menubar = self.win.menubar.addMenu("results")
q_menubar.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: red;""}")
new_q = q_menubar.addMenu("sub-menu0")
new_q.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: orange;""}")
a1 = new_q.addMenu("sub-menu1")
a2 = new_q.addMenu("sub-menu2")
a3 = new_q.addMenu("sub-menu3")
a4 = new_q.addMenu("sub-menu4")

a1.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: green;""}")
a2.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: blue;""}")
a3.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: purple;""}")
a4.setStyleSheet("QMenu::item {""color: yellow;""}")
```

[image: The results]

I wish for:

a. a green colored sub-menu1

b. a blue colored sub-menu2

etc.

Comment: If yoi mean the menu *item* associated to a submenu, it's not possible through style sheets. The only way is to subclass QMenu and override the `paintEvent()`.

Comment: @musicamante I meant that I want each sub-menuX to be in a different color. Didn't get to any solution yet, but I'll to read about paintEvent

Comment: The submenu is the *content* of the menu inside a "parent" menu, while what you seem to be referring to is the *item* (the QAction item, in Qt terms) that is associated to that menu and is shown *in* the parent menu.

Comment: @musicamante I'm new to Qt, so excuse me... I don't understand why would they call what's inside a "parent" menu - QMenu, but the items themselves are QAction... Or am I incorrect?

Comment: @musicamante I just read again the documentation and I see that QWidgets that have submenus are considered as QMenu, and those who are "leaf" are QAction. I want to know how to paint any of them. Could you please provide an example of paintEvent?

Comment: I'm afraid you're still a bit confused. QMenu (a subclass of QWidget) is used to show a list of QActions, which are abstract Qt objects that can be displayed in various ways. QMenu also has a "menu action", a QAction that can be added to another QMenu (or QMenuBar) to show that menu. That said, the C++ implementation alone is almost 150 lines of code, which is not *that* much, but porting it to python *and* adding customization would make it much longer and more complex. Sorry, but I won't do that: I'd have to completely rewrite the code *for you*, and that's not the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to learn the basic of Qt painting through [QPainter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) and how Qt uses [QStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html) functions to actually draw widgets (including QMenu and its contents), so that you can begin to understand how QMenu's `paintEvent` is implemented by studying the Qt sources (maybe through the woboq code browser: https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qmenu.cpp.html#_ZN5QMenu10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent).